# How to show a notice if whatsapp sharing is not available?

Tags: android, share, whatsapp

Let's say, I'm on desktop, or on Android which has no WhatsApp application. I press it and nothing happens. A notice message ought to be shown, like "Install the WhatsApp application!" or something like that. All I have is this:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=text">Click here to share!</a>
```

I tried these:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send/?phone=62812345678&amp;text=test" id="openWA">Send to WhatsApp</a>
<br>
<a href="viber://forward?text=paff" id="openV">Send to Viber</a>

<!-- Auto open on WebView and Firefox -->

<script>
    document.querySelector('#openWA').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var f = Date.now(),
            j = setTimeout(function() {
                if (Date.now() - f > 1250)
                    return;
                alert('WA not installed')
            }, 1e3);
    });
    document.querySelector('#openV').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var f = Date.now(),
            j = setTimeout(function() {
                if (Date.now() - f > 1250)
                    return;
                alert('VIBER not installed')
            }, 1e3);
    });
</script>
```

but it say "not installed", either it is or not.

Comment: You press *what* and nothing happens?

Comment: I press that "click here to share!" link

Answer (score 2):

**Consider sending some type of data to Native Android and handling it
there**

use the below method to find out if an application is installed in Java
but you need to know the package name of the application

```
public static boolean isAppInstalled(Context context, String packageName) {
    try {
        context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
        return true;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
if(isAppInstalled(context,"com.Whatsapp") == false){

      //show toast saying whatsapp is not available
}
```

**you can send data from webView to native layer using the below method**

1. Create an interface in native layer, which will enable webview to connect the native layer and pass data.

```
class JSBridge(){
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun showMessageInNative(message:String){
        //Received message from webview in native, call isAppInstalled(...) here

        // for example 

        if(message == "whatsapp"){

             if(isAppInstalled(context,"com.whatsapp") == false){

                    //show toast saying whatsapp is not available
             }
         }
    }
```

2. From inside your script layer, call this method. (edit valueToBePassed to send whatsapp or viber or something)

```
function sendMessage() {
  
      JSBridge.showMessageInNative(valueToBePassed);
  }
```

3. While configuring web view, we need to set JavaScript interface as above JSBridge class.

```
mWebViewComponent.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
mWebViewComponent.addJavascriptInterface(JSBridge(),"JSBridge")
```